# Hyperlink in ContentEditorWebPart Content Fails

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I have a ContentEditorWebPart in visual studio 2010.  I have altered the content and added some html.  When i deploy this it works fine.

When i add a hyperlink to the content the deployment fails.  It only happens when hyperlinks are included in the content.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you tries to provision a CEWP by feature. In this case I think you should escape some symbols in your web part definition. The best way, I think, is to add CEWP to the page, add html manually, and do export web part action. After this you can download exported web part to your PC and open file in visual studio. In this file you can find out correct content that should be included in provision.